# LogStash setup LoadError

Tags: ruby, jruby, logstash

I'm trying to set up LogStash and I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html#_moving_on) exactly. But when I run command 
`bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'` 
it gives me the following error:

```
warning: --1.9 ignored
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
  require at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
   setup! at C:/Users/ryan.dai/Desktop/logstash-1.5.3/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:43
    <top> at c:/Users/ryan.dai/Desktop/logstash-1.5.3/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:46
```

I tried `jruby -S gem install bundler` as suggested from someone else but it doesn't work. Totally new to Ruby, what is happening and what should I do?

Comment: Did it fail to install the bundler gem?

Comment: @JeremyRodi nah it says successfully installed bundler-1.10.6

Answer (score 0):

You can fallow the below `URL` for installing entire `ELK Setup`.

Here you need to pass the `file(log)` as a path to the input of the logstash configuration.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/access_log"
    start_position => "beginning"
   }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

[ELK Setup Installtion](http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/install-elasticsearch-kibana-logstash-on-windows.html)

**Commands for running with CMD Prompt:**

`logstash -f logstash.conf`    for running logstash

`logstash --configtest -f logstash.conf`   for configuration test

`logstash --debug -f logstash.conf`     for debug the logstash configuration

[Logstash configuration Examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html)